# Generically transforming a type in Scala

Tags: scala, types, type-conversion

Is there a way of transforming a type in a generic manner? I currently have something like this:

```
class Super {
  type MessagesType = Product
  type AggregatorType = Product
}

class Sub1 {
   override type MessagesType = (Class1, Class2)
   override type AggregatorType = (Option[Class1], Option[Class2])
}

class Sub2 {
   override type MessagesType = (Class1, Class2, Class3)
   override type AggregatorType = (Option[Class1], Option[Class2], Option[Class3])
}
```

The `AggregatorType` will always contain `Option`s of each of the types in the `MessagesType`. I've been looking at ways of declaring only the `MessagesType` in `Sub` and having the corresponding `AggregatorType` generated automatically. While I'm currently using `Tuple`s, I could change it to be `HList`s, case classes, or whatever. However, I do have the limitation of using Shapeless 1.2.4 (due to some transitive dependencies).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Mapped` type class from shapeless for this.

It is a little bit difficult to get the compiler to infer most of the types. I used a nested class, maybe someone else can come up with a prettier solution.

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{Mapped, Tupler}

class WithMessage[Message <: Product] {
  class Super[
    G <: HList,
    M <: HList,
    T <: Product
  ](implicit 
    gen: Generic.Aux[Message, G],  // from tuple to generic (HList) representation
    map: Mapped.Aux[G, Option, M], // all elements of the G HList in an Option
    tup: Tupler.Aux[M, T]          // from HList M back to a tuple
  ) {
    type Aggregator = T
    // ...
  }
}
```

Which can be used as :

```
val StringIntMsg = new WithMessage[(String, Int)]
object SI extends StringIntMsg.Super

val si: SI.Aggregator = (Some("foo"), Some(1))
```

Comment: This looks interesting... but there's an additional problem. Due to some transitive dependencies I have to use Shapeless 1.2.4, not Shapeless 2.x :(

Comment: I think it should be possible to convert this to 1.2.4 (which has `.tupled`, `.hlisted` and `Mapped` which was added in 1.2.3).